Two-point probe volume resistance how to measure without guard?
So I have measured the surface resistance of a highly insulative material using a Megger MIT 420/2 and a two-point probe. But how would I go about measuring volume resistance? The Megger has no guard so a bit lost with what to do with one of the probe leads. What is typically done? Just covering it with an insulated cap?

